# How to search for a partial and an absolute in excel to get an answer?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a worksheet, in where I need a search that does more than one query. The problem I am running into is this:

On the workbook there are two tabs, the first is Jobs, the second is OOR. In OOR there are multiple columns empty, **Order Qty.**, **Orig Promise Date**, and **Shop Order**.

Now I know there are duplicates, and this is fine, what I am looking at now is to use Column B in OOR is a refrence. So in this case use B3 as the refrence point. which is a partial number of `48900421 Rev 2`. What I want to do is this, use two refrence points.

I want to look up B3 in **OOR**, and use two points of refrence to gurantee the correct job is refrenced. Those two columns to refrence is in **Jobs**. The first is Column B which will always equal `Dakota Systems, Inc.`, and the other will reference Column C, but this is where I don't know what to do here, I since `C3` in **OOR** only shows 48900421, it will never find `48900421 Rev 2`I thought about using something like this:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Jobs!$E:$E,MATCH(1,INDEX((OOR!$C:$C=$B3)*(Jobs!$C:$C="Dakota Systems, Inc."),1),0)),"")`

But for some reason I am getting a blank when I don't think I should be. I'm loosing my sanity this late in the week, can someone help?

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3327208/Excel/twosearches.xlsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to be referencing the right columns....and also you need a zero in the second INDEX function, not a 1

Try this version in in OOR!I3 copied down, using `ISNUMBER(FIND` to find your part number within other text:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Jobs!E$3:E$1000,MATCH(1,INDEX(ISNUMBER(FIND(B3,Jobs!C$3:C$1000))*(Jobs!B$3:B$1000="Dakota Systems, Inc."),0),0)),"")`

format in required date format

**Revised re comment below:**

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Jobs!E$3:E$1000,MATCH(1,INDEX(ISNUMBER(FIND(B3,Jobs!C$3:C$1000))*(Jobs!B$3:B$1000="Dakota Systems, Inc.")*(Jobs!A$3:A$1000=M3),0),0)),"")`

Comment: Is there a way to do this between two points of refrence? Such as the part number and shop order? I only ask because I feel more secure knowing that I can have two refrence points instead of one...

Comment: I see that the "shop order" column is blank in OOR sheet but assuming that was populated and had to match against column A in jobs then you could add another condition - see revised formula in my answer - the formula would then return the first date where all 3 conditions match, if any

Comment: Thanks. this will save me a lot of headache :)